# Yii CRedisCache.php will use which redis datatype for cache storage?

Tags: php, caching, yii, redis

I've studied **Redis** recently and i decided to ***use it as Cache storage in my PHP-Yii application..***
Another decision i am convinced on is, i want to store cached data in form of HashMaps.
Only problem is i dont know, about internal storage of this code..

```
Yii::app()->cache()->set($id,$value);
```

whether it will use lists, set, hashmaps or wat else? and if i could configure it somehow to use a particular data type..for performance measurement..!

**there is no official description on Yii homepage.**

**FYI** : *CRedisCache* is the class provided by Yii for cache management on Redis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may found that in [CRedisCache sources](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/caching/CRedisCache.php) - this class uses string keys (i.e. `SET`, `SETNX` commands)

Comment: ummm, executeCommand() function may give me flexibility to use, HashMaps then, by using HSET command

Comment: yes, but keep in mind - HSET do not allow you to use TTL or expire on your cache key fields.

Comment: Yii:app()->cache()->executecommand(); just wont work.. is there someother syntax for it??

Comment: Look at class sources - this method has nice docblock.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23632968/cannot-run-redis-command-using-crediscache
see this question to know exact problem..its probably not about the class itself

Answer (score 2):

Since **CRedisCache.php** extends **Ccache.php** , whatever data you set to the redis will be serialized by using serialized() and stored in redis, while getting data back from redis it unserialize() your data and gives back to you.